# Inheritence with ndb.Model based classes, Python

Tags: python

I currently have a project that is using the following code:

Classes.py

```
class Session(Conference, ndb.Model):
    ''' Session - A Session object '''
    # The session's name
    sessionName     = ndb.StringProperty()
    # Highlights of the session
    highlights      = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
    # The session's speaker
    speaker         = ndb.StringProperty()
    # How long the session will last
    duration        = ndb.TimeProperty()
    # The type of session (Workshop, lecture, etc...); Default 'Not Specified'
    typeOfSession   = ndb.StringProperty(default = 'NOT_SPECIFIED')
    # Date the session takes place on
    date            = ndb.DateProperty()
    # The time the session starts
    startTime       = ndb.TimeProperty()
    # The Conference this Session is at
    parentConf      = Conference

class Conference(ndb.Model):
    '''Conference -- Conference object'''
    name            = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description     = ndb.StringProperty()
    organizerUserId = ndb.StringProperty()
    topics          = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    city            = ndb.StringProperty()
    startDate       = ndb.DateProperty()
    month           = ndb.IntegerProperty() # TODO: do we need for indexing like Java?
    endDate         = ndb.DateProperty()
    maxAttendees    = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    seatsAvailable  = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

and am trying to call the code
    conf = Conference(**data).put()
    variable = Session(conf,**data).put()

where conf is a Conference object (I've verified this)
**data is an input data array, which works (I've tested this)
but when I call this function, I get the error

'TypeError: Model constructor takes no positional arguments.'

Which after some searching I have found to be due to me attempting to overload the constructor of the ndb.Model, which I've been informed I shouldn't be doing.

So my question is, how would I manage this kind of inheritance, where Session is a child of Conference, but still takes ndb.Model data during it's construction? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use PolyModel for datastore inheritance -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

Here is an example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import polymodel

class Contact(polymodel.PolyModel):
  phone_number = ndb.PhoneNumberProperty()
  address = ndb.PostalAddressProperty()

class Person(Contact):
  first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  mobile_number = ndb.PhoneNumberProperty()

class Company(Contact):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  fax_number = ndb.PhoneNumberProperty()

p = Person(phone_number='1-206-555-9234',
           address='123 First Ave., Seattle, WA, 98101',
           first_name='Alfred',
           last_name='Smith',
           mobile_number='1-206-555-0117')
p.put()

c = Company(phone_number='1-503-555-9123',
            address='P.O. Box 98765, Salem, OR, 97301',
            name='Data Solutions, LLC',
            fax_number='1-503-555-6622')
c.put()

for contact in Contact.query():
  print 'Phone: %s\nAddress: %s\n\n' % (contact.phone_number, contact.address)
```